# Is it possible to use ArrayInput as just array?

Tags: admin-on-rest, react-admin

Is it possible to use `ArrayInput` as just array?

Probably not just `ArrayInput` but also be `CheckboxGroupInput`, `SelectArrayInput`

Here is an example of data.

```
{
  id: 123,
  backlinks: ['http://example.com/foo/bar.html', 'https://blog.johndoe.com/2012/08/12/foobar.html']
}
```

Is it possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

We are working on it. No ETA yet though